# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given (Python multiprocessing with Pytesseract)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-tesseract

I'm receiving the error message below when attempting to use Python's `multiprocessing` library along with `pytesseract` and `pdf2image` and I'm not quite sure what it means or how to correct it. Other posts I've seen with a similar output message deal with passing `self` as an argument within a class's method, but I haven't created a class in this instance.

```
C:\Users\erik7>python "C:\Users\erik7\Documents\Python Projects\multiprocess_test2.py"
0
Exception in thread Thread-11:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\erik7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\erik7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\erik7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 576, in _handle_results
    task = get()
  File "C:\Users\erik7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

My code:

```
import pytesseract
import pdf2image
import multiprocessing


def extract(img, page_num):
    
    print(page_num)
    
    return pytesseract.image_to_osd(img, output_type = pytesseract.Output.DICT)['orientaton']


if __name__ == "__main__":

    pdf_path = r"C:/Users/erik7/Documents/Late Scans for Testing/scans_template2.pdf"
    output_fmt = 'jpeg'
    img_dpi = 300
    pop_path = r"C:\Users\erik7\Downloads\poppler-0.90.1\bin"
    output_path = r"C:\Users\erik7\Downloads"
    
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
    
    converted_path = r"C:\Users\erik7\Downloads\converted_images"
    converted = pdf2image.convert_from_path(pdf_path = pdf_path, fmt = output_fmt, dpi = img_dpi, poppler_path = pop_path, output_folder = converted_path, grayscale = True, thread_count = 2)

    results = [] 
    
    iterable = [[img, page_num] for page_num, img in enumerate(converted)]
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    r = p.starmap(extract, iterable)
    results.append(r)
    p.close()
    
    print("\n**PROCESS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working. I needed to move `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"` to within my `extract` function as so and the program as able to run successfully using `multiprocessing`:

```
import pytesseract
import pdf2image
import multiprocessing


def extract(img, page_num):
    
    print(page_num)
    
    return pytesseract.image_to_osd(img, output_type = pytesseract.Output.DICT)['orientaton']


if __name__ == "__main__":

    pdf_path = r"C:/Users/erik7/Documents/Late Scans for Testing/scans_template2.pdf"
    output_fmt = 'jpeg'
    img_dpi = 300
    pop_path = r"C:\Users\erik7\Downloads\poppler-0.90.1\bin"
    output_path = r"C:\Users\erik7\Downloads"
    
    converted_path = r"C:\Users\erik7\Downloads\converted_images"
    converted = pdf2image.convert_from_path(pdf_path = pdf_path, fmt = output_fmt, dpi = img_dpi, poppler_path = pop_path, output_folder = converted_path, grayscale = True, thread_count = 2)

    results = [] 
    
    iterable = [[img, page_num] for page_num, img in enumerate(converted)]
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    r = p.starmap(extract, iterable)
    results.append(r)
    p.close()
    
    print("\n**PROCESS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY")
```

Comment: Hi @erik7970, I have a similar problem to your's but I never use pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe" in [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69290984/multiprocessing-using-pools-keeps-throwing-positional-argument-error). I can't find it back under extract in your solution aswell. Could you help me figure out what might be the issue at hand in my problem?